# Angular 9 - Custom library with external libraries not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm creating a new angular library and is trying to add material cdk to it but I can't run it locally after the material cdk was added

here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-lib",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "9.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "9.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "9.1.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0"
  }
}
```

and my ng-package.json

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/my-lib",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts"
  },
  "assets": ["./assets/*"]
}
```

I'm following the steps here https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#using-your-own-library-in-apps